# Button inside Cardview is not clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-cardview

I have a CardView containing ImageView and some buttons inside a fragment. When i set up the click event listener on any of those buttons with setOnClickListener this event is not fired when button is clicked!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ui.wallpaper.WallpaperFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Media -->
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="194dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:contentDescription="description here"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <!-- Title -->
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="lorem ipsum"
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- Buttons -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <!-- Buttons -->
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/applyButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Apply"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/favouriteButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="Favorite"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/shareButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Share"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

The click event handler is defined as bellow :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wallpaper, container, false);
        Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
        Log.d("INFO", button.getText().toString());
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something in response to button click
                Log.d("STATE","Button share clicked !");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This is my Toast message!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    return rootView;
}
```

Any Idea? When i am clicking on the share button for example it does not display log message; it doesn't fire the event.
Thank you!

Comment: are u returning the inflated view? like, return rootView; at the end of the onCreateView function?

Comment: Move your relevant code to `onViewCreated(...)`. `onCreateView` should only be used to create the views. You can assign the click listeners in onViewCreated once the views have been... well.. created :)